# mod_rewrite force internal redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My goal is to reduce the visibility of my app's signature. This is not security by obscurity, just a superficial bit of defence in depth, so that at first glance an attacker cannot tell if it is a static site or not. (Also cosmetic; it just feels "cleaner" to hide app details even if they would never become visible in normal operation). Therefore I want to deny access to some directories without revealing that they exist, so I must give the exact same 404 response my app would give if the user requested a non-existent page.

In an `.htaccess` file, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-f"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-d"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "index.php?page=$1"
RewriteRule "^(secret_dir1|secret_dir2)(/.*)?$" "index.php?page=404"
```

where `index.php` renders a nice pretty webpage according to the value of the "page" GET parameter; if "page" does not correspond to a page at the app level, or "page" is set to 404, the script renders a pretty 404 page with proper headers and everything.

Here's where the problem happens. "App-level" 404s work as expected; a 404 page is rendered. However, if the user requests `mydomain.com/dir_i_am_trying_to_hide`, they are given a 301 redirect to `mydomain.com/dir_i_am_trying_to_hide/?page=404`: an external redirect instead of an internal rewrite.

Why is it sending out an external redirect instead of just rewriting the url? How am I supposed to avoid this properly? Barring that, *is there a way to force the server to do an internal rewrite* instead? (The Apache docs seem to indicate you can force a RewriteRule to be external, but not the other way around)

Comment: to be clear, `^dir_i_am_trying_to_hide` is not the real regex :D

Comment: These rules should not cause 301. Perhaps something inside your index.php is doing it?

Comment: I can't imagine what. I only have one call to the header() function in the entire application, and that is `header("${_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]} 404 Not Found");` before rendering the 404 page.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that I have a VirtualHost for port 80 with `Redirect permanent / https://domain`, although I can't imagine how that would be connected either

Comment: I have noticed something interesting: If I `curl domain/.git` I get a redirect to `domain/.git/`, but if I `curl domain/.git/` I get the proper response. So this makes sense. My question now becomes how do I disable redirecting to add trailing slashes to directory names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my rewrite rule was not causing the external redirect; Apache's `DirectorySlash` was; I would query `hostname/secret_dir1` and it would send a redirect to `hostname/secret_dir1/`.

I'm not sure why the query string was changed, but adding `DirectorySlash off` fixed it.