# How to get mod_rewrite to redirect internally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching since yesterday to find a solution to my problem.

This is my current `.htacces` file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^l/(\w+)/?$    sites/$1    [L]    # Handle shortlink
```

I would like `http://drop2upload.danschalow.com/l/58032bf6b1917/` to point to `http://drop2upload.danschalow.com/sites/58032bf6b1917/`.

Now, if you click on http://drop2upload.danschalow.com/l/58032bf6b1917/ you will find that you are returned a page. What you get however, is a `301 Moved Permanently`, which means the user 'sees' that he has been redirected.

How do I redirect the user internally, without him knowing.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: The above rule does not send a http status 301. There has to be some other reason for that. Maybe an internal mechanism of some application you operate under that URL?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am brand new to `mod_rewrite` and definitely haven't set anything up internally. Is it possibly something my hosting provider could have predefined?

Comment: I don't see how that would be an option.

Comment: Where did you get that information from that you actually received a 301 for that request? And are you certain that this is not a cached result you see?

Comment: I see the `301` in the response when I go to `http://drop2upload.danschalow.com/l/58032bf6b1917/`. Does that mean, that you are not getting the `301`?

Comment: Yep, same thing here, indeed. No idea though. That rewrite rule does in internal redirection. Please take a look into your http servers log files. First, obviously into the error log which always is worth a look. But more important: configure your htttp server to raise the logging level for redirections, setup a redirection log file and monitor that. It allows a deep insight into what exactly is going on inside your rewrite engine. The documentation explains how to do that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Many thanks, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I have found my answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383019/mod-rewrite-force-internal-redirect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383019/mod-rewrite-force-internal-redirect